# php exec('ps -aeo') doesn't return all processes

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos, ps

I'm trying to build a simple php script to return a JSON formatted list of running processes.

This script of course is executed by apache.

I have everything figured out except one little detail. When the script is executed by apache the command only returns a list of running processes that are owned by the 'apache' user.

Is there anyway around this?

```
exec('ps -aeo',$output);
//then some code to parse the $output and return a JSON string
```

OUTPUT:

```
"processes": [
    {
      "cpu": "0.0",
      "pid": "23698",
      "user": "apache",
      "command": "/usr/sbin/httpd"
    },
    {
      "cpu": "0.0",
      "pid": "23486",
      "user": "apache",
      "command": "/usr/sbin/httpd"
    },
    {
      "cpu": "0.0",
      "pid": "23485",
      "user": "apache",
      "command": "/usr/sbin/httpd"
    },
    {
      "cpu": "0.0",
      "pid": "23484",
      "user": "apache",
      "command": "/usr/sbin/httpd"
    },
    {
      "cpu": "0.0",
      "pid": "23483",
      "user": "apache",
      "command": "/usr/sbin/httpd"
    },
    {
      "cpu": "0.0",
      "pid": "23482",
      "user": "apache",
      "command": "/usr/sbin/httpd"
    },
    {
      "cpu": "0.0",
      "pid": "23481",
      "user": "apache",
      "command": "/usr/sbin/httpd"
    },
    {
      "cpu": "0.0",
      "pid": "23480",
      "user": "apache",
      "command": "/usr/sbin/httpd"
    },
    {
      "cpu": "0.0",
      "pid": "23479",
      "user": "apache",
      "command": "/usr/sbin/httpd"
    },
    {
      "cpu": "0.0",
      "pid": "23478",
      "user": "apache",
      "command": "/usr/sbin/httpd"
    },
    {
      "cpu": "0.0",
      "pid": "1008",
      "user": "root",
      "command": "/usr/sbin/httpd"
    },
    {
      "cpu": "0.0",
      "pid": "959",
      "user": "root",
      "command": "/usr/sbin/abrtd"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Try 'ps aux' to lift the "this user only" restriction.

Comment: @cwscribner Beat me to it. Yep. Although you may end up with some formatting issues as a result of this, suck as the `strikethrough`.

Comment: I just did something similar recently. Maybe looking at my code will help you ;) http://geneticcoder.blogspot.com/2014/10/php-process-manager-with-top.html

Comment: @cwscribner no luck with 'aux', still only outputs apache owned processes.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy didn't work sadly

Comment: Then your Linux has some kind of extra permission-limiting feature switched on for `/proc`, something like Grsecurity, or similar.

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem, this solved it. (assuming you have root privileges)

```
# chcon -t unconfined_exec_t /sbin/httpd
```

[see detailed document here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Managing_Confined_Services/sect-Managing_Confined_Services-Targeted_policy-Unconfined_processes.html)

probably not a good idea if the server is shared by untrustful users